# openv HSV is soo noisy

Tags: opencv, hsv

Good day

I am try to filter video by subtracting some colors in specified range.
but while the recorded image is still or not changed but the HSV filtered image looks shaken and not stable.
this shake or instability cause lot's of problem in my processing.
is there any way that I can filter image in stable way

this is sample code of my filter ... part of the code

```
while (1)
    {
        //first frame read
        cap.read(origonal1);
        morphOps(origonal1);
        cvtColor(origonal1, HSV1, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

        inRange(HSV1, Scalar(0, 129,173), Scalar(26,212, 255), thresholdImage1);



        waitKey(36);

        //second image read and convert it to HSV
        cap.read(origonal2);
        morphOps(origonal2);
        cvtColor(origonal2, HSV2, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

        inRange(HSV2, Scalar(28, 89, 87), Scalar(93, 255, 255),thresholdImage2);

        morphOps(thresholdImage1);
        morphOps(thresholdImage2);
//create a mask so that i only detect motion of certain color range and don't 
//care about other colors motion detection
        maskImage = thresholdImage1 | thresholdImage2;

        //make the difference between images

        absdiff(thresholdImage1,thresholdImage2,imageDifference);

        imageDifference = imageDifference&maskImage;
        morphOps(imageDifference);
        imshow("threshold Image", imageDifference);
        //search for movement now update the origonal image
        searchForMovement(thresholdImage1, origonal1);
        imshow("origonal", origonal1);
        imshow("HSV", HSV1);
        imshow("threshold1", thresholdImage1);
        imshow("threshold2", thresholdImage2);
        //wait for a while give a break to the processor
        //waitKey(1000); 

    }
```

[image]
[image]
[image: this is sample of first input image .. let's say want to filter orange paper]
[image: this is example of second input]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post sample images to show that behaviour? and post code how you filter/convert your hsv images

Comment: you can see the details you requested tell me if anything else needed

Comment: probably, displaying a hsv image as a bgr image isnt intuitive since red color is split between beginning and end of the first channel. can you post 2 input images so I can have a look at values?

Comment: am not sure what you mean two input images but here is the source image BGR i upload it.. any way if you have an idea about stable way to filter color I ll be happy to hear

Comment: have you tried bilateral filter or guided filter.

Comment: the function morphOps() I added do some sort of filtering but they are not that accurate or helpful for my case .. am trying to detect motion but the filtered image already contain inaccurate motion

Comment: How does the HSV image looks like if you convert it back to BGR right before displaying? Maybe it is just a display problem...

Comment: I thought you say the color is noisy between two images although the camera is still. that's why I ask for two images to see the noise.

Comment: you will not be able to see the difference between too images because this noise is small pixels distributed all over the image .. but when you make motion tracking it makes a lot of problems

Comment: so in single images you want to remove noise (e.g. make those pink pixel in your hsv displayed image red)?  did you try median filtering? one problem if you flter the hue channel is that value 0 is equal to value 180 which means that typical filters might "average" values of e.g. [3, 0, 1, 60 ,180, 177, 179]. in this example 60 is the only outlier while the others are all color "red". in this sample, median and average filters will give very bad results. you'll need some kind of "circle-closed-fltering" (probably wrong name) or filter in bgr space

Comment: but: if you post two images of still camera we might be able to test some filtering for you ;)

Comment: i have upload two input frames in RGB format ... if you need me to upload two hsv images converted that is not soo hard though

Comment: ok. Here your problem isn't inter-image noise but Hue noise. That's in your case because hue value may be very noisy (and is irrelevant) if either saturation channel is very low (white) or value channel is very low (black). Since your images are mostly bright colors that might be the problem (low saturation value).

Comment: thank you for reply .what would you suggest for me . change the camera or the detection algorithm or anything.and can I contact you somehow

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
fastNlMeansDenoisingColored( frame, frame_result, 3, 3, 7, 21 );
```

it's too slow but good for trying.